# Python3 - Set save path

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am *very* new to Python. I just started today.

I am trying desperately to save an image to a fixed path, such as:

```
/Users/myname/Sites/Tester/images/
```

So if I have an image, called "1.jpg", it will be placed here:

```
/Users/myname/Sites/Tester/images/1.jpg
```

This is my script:

```
from PIL import Image
import tempfile



def set_image_dpi(file_path):
    im = Image.open(file_path)

    length_x, width_y = im.size
    factor = min(1, float(1024.0 / length_x))
    size = int(factor * length_x), int(factor * width_y)
    im_resized = im.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False,   suffix='.jpg')
    temp_filename = temp_file.name


    im_resized.save(temp_filename, dpi=(300, 300))

    return temp_filename
```

However, this saves the file in:

```
/var/folders/1n/hdyfv8z96v5_hcb9tsgvt7cr0000gn/T/tmp91rams5v.jpg
```

How can I do, so it will save in the path I specifies?

```
"MY_PATH / temp_filename"
```

Comment: So... you want to save the image to a specific path... but instead you create a temporary file and save the image there. What the heck? Why?

Comment: @Aran-Fey As said, I am brand new to Python and have no prior experience. I am just trying here. I thought that the `temp_file` would create the specific file (as the name indicates), and then I could save that file to a specific folder afterwards?

Comment: But you don't need or want a temporary file. Just pass `"/Users/myname/Sites/Tester/images/1.jpg"` to `im_resized.save(...)`.

Comment: Just FYI, `NamedTemporaryFile` has an argument to specify the path where it should be created, but like @Aran-Fey said, you don't need/want a tempfile here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the `tempfile` module here, you just need to specify the path when calling `.save()`:

```
from PIL import Image
import os

def set_image_dpi(file_path, save_folder):
    im = Image.open(file_path)

    length_x, width_y = im.size
    factor = min(1, float(1024.0 / length_x))
    size = int(factor * length_x), int(factor * width_y)
    im_resized = im.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

    save_path = os.path.join(save_folder,'test.png')
    # creates path: C:\Users\User\Pictures\test.png

    im_resized.save(save_path, dpi=(300, 300))

set_image_dpi('test.png','C:\\Users\\User\\Pictures')
```

Comment: Better use `os.path.join(save_path, filename)` instead of string concatenation.

Comment: What's the difference between string concatenation and `os.path.join()`?

Comment: `os.path.join()` will always give you a syntactically valid path.

Comment: `os.path.join()` works cross-platform and readability counts.

Comment: @ThiefMaster even better, use `Path(save_path) / filename` from [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your main problem is building the result path from the original path (something like `/where/images/are/taken/from/1.jpg`) and your destination directory (`/Users/myname/Sites/Tester/images/`). The methods in the `os.path` package can help (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html):

```py
import os

dest_dir = '/Users/myname/Sites/Tester/images/'

...

base = os.path.basename(file_path) # this will be '1.jpg'
dest_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, base) # this will be the full path
im_resized.save(dest_path)
```

As others have said in the comments, you don't need `tempfile` here.